# Can not construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm loading properties from a json file and creating datasource builder in spring boot app. But when I try to update the values into json file, I'm getting the error **[Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value]**. Please find below code and help me out in this.

I have used "PropertySource" annotation for a class to load data from a json. I'm trying update those values into json file using ObjectMapper.

### 1. JsonProperties.class (class for json)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/config/database_config.json", factory = JsonPropertySourceFactory.class)
@ConfigurationProperties
public class JsonProperties {

    private String ip;
    private String port;

        //getters and setters
}
```

### 2. JsonPropertySourceFactory.class (parser)

```
public class JsonPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Map.class);
        return new MapPropertySource("json-property", readValue);
    }

}
```

### 3. database_config.json (data)

```
{
    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
    "port": "3306",
}
```

### 4. Trying to update json file dynamically

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    mapper.writeValue(new ClassPathResource("configuration/database_config.json").getFile(), dataBaseJsonProperties);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying to update the database info in json file and restart the application by looking into json file again to check database.

Comment: at least stacktrace plz....